# Cannot run pygame or examples given by pygame in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using Ubuntu as my command line and I have installed pygame using `pip install pygame`.
I have also checked with `pygame --version` in a python terminal and it says that pygame is installed correctly but despite this I am unable to run pygame code featured in Python Crash Course or `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens` (an example code provided by pygame documentation).

Whenever I run `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`  in the terminal I get:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Warning, no sound
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/aidanrogers02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/examples/aliens.py", line 400, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/aidanrogers02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/examples/aliens.py", line 243, in main
    bestdepth = pg.display.mode_ok(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, 32)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: "I am using Ubuntu as my command line." What version of Ubuntu are you using, and how did you install it?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4